# Impinj: How to get an event when rfid tag goes out of range?

Tags: c#, rfid, octane-sdk

How do we configure reader to fire an event when the tag moves out of RFID reader read range?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure that Octane SDK gives you such an event.  We wrote a piece of middleware that tracks tags read and last timestamp, so that we are only sending them to a web service once per time allotment.  If I wanted to implement out-of-range monitoring in my situation, I would set a timer to check for any tags in the database that have a timestamp older than some number of seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the absence detection module with Tagit Trapeze middleware. This functionality is out of the box